# Opening remote documents in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, document

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString

datasource = open('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml')
dom = parse(datasource)

print dom
```

... the above code throws an `IOError: 2, 'No such file or directory'`. Python doesn't read remote doc like PHP? What do I need to change in the code to make it read the XML file?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`urllib2.urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
>>> u1=urllib2.urlopen('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml')
>>> dom=parse(u1)
>>> print dom
<xml.dom.minidom.Document instance at 0x017D73A0>
>>> dom.childNodes
[<DOM Element: gesmes:Envelope at 0x17d7c88>]
>>> dom.childNodes[0].childNodes
[<DOM Text node "u'\n\t'">, <DOM Element: gesmes:subject at 0x1041aa8>,
 <DOM Text node "u'\n\t'">, <DOM Element: gesmes:Sender at 0xff8260>,
 <DOM Text node "u'\n\t'">, <DOM Element: Cube at 0x17d3dc8>, <DOM Text node "u'\n'">]
>>>
```

This XML uses a `Cube` tag for too many constructs, so selecting currencies gets a little heady.

```
>>> [elem.attributes['currency'].value for elem in
     dom.getElementsByTagName('Cube') if elem.hasAttribute('currency')]
[u'USD', u'JPY', u'BGN', u'CZK', u'DKK', u'EEK', u'GBP', u'HUF', u'LTL', u'LVL',
 u'PLN', u'RON', u'SEK', u'CHF', u'NOK', u'HRK', u'RUB', u'TRY', u'AUD', u'BRL',
 u'CAD', u'CNY', u'HKD', u'IDR', u'INR', u'KRW', u'MXN', u'MYR', u'NZD', u'PHP',
 u'SGD', u'THB', u'ZAR']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

`open` is used to open a file on a local filesystem. It cannot open URLs. You have to use `urllib.urlopen` which returns a file like object that supports a subset of the API.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`urllib.urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen).

Comment: urllib2.urlopen() does the same thing I believe, but it is also forward compatible with v3.0

Answer (score 0):

The [urllib.urlopen()](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) method returns a [File Object](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects). So you can directly pass it to your `parse()` method

Answer (score 0):

```
    import urllib.request
    from xml.dom import minidom

    response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml')
    results = response.read()

    #print(results)     


    xmldoc = minidom.parseString(results)
    itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Cube') 
    # if itemlist[1].hasAttribute('time'): 
    #     print("Yes it has")
    # for s in itemlist[2].attributes.values():
    #     print(s.value)     
    #     print(itemlist[2].attributes.values())

    for s in itemlist:
        if s.hasAttribute('currency'):
            print(s.attributes['currency'].value + ' ' + s.attributes['rate'].value)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Please explain the code, too. It is better if the OP can understand the concept, and does not just get a copy/paste content since that is more educative.